# Functional React Components Hooks ---- I want to add play/pause functionality in video list (functional component)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const VideoList = ({ videoList }) => {
let stateArr:any=[]
for(let i=0;i<content.videoListItems.length;i++){
stateArr[i]=true
}
const [iconDisplay, setIconHide] = useState(stateArr);   
const stopVideo=(e:any,index:any)=>{
stateArr[index]=true
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.previousSibling.pause();
}
const videoPlay=(e:any,index:any)=>{
stateArr[index]=false
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.previousSibling.play();
}
useEffect(() => {
setIconHide(stateArr);
}, []);
return (
<div>
   {videoListItems.map((item: any, index: number) => {    //rendering video list
   return (
   <div key={index}>
      <video src={item.video.url} />
      <span>
      {iconDisplay[index] &&<button onClick={(e:any)=>videoPlay(e,index)}>
      <img                               // rendering play image
         src="play.svg"
         alt="Play Icon"
         />
      </button>}
      {!iconDisplay[index] && <button onClick={(e:any)=>stopVideo(e,index)}>
      <img
         src="pause.svg"                  //rendering pause image
         alt="Pause Icon"
         />
      </button>
      }
      </span>
   </div>
   )
   })
   }
</div>
)
}
```

How can I achieve this functionality. I am trying to render list of videos and based on the event click trying to play and pause but somehow I am unable to render pause image after 1st click

Comment: Your `let stateArr=[]` and `for all i's make stateArr[i] = true` is in the render loop. That code will run every time the component re-renders so it won't update like you expect. stateArr should probably be react state (useState), and you'll want to update by creating a new stateArr object, not mutating the original.

Comment: Is there any reason why you might need to know which videos in the list are playing?  Rather than updating an element in an array, I think it would be much easier if you render each video through a `Video` component that manages its own pause/play state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making this over-complicated by managing your state in an `array`.  It can be done, but mutating the state by setting `stateArr[index]=true` is not the way.

You can make this a lot easier for yourself if you have a `Video` component for each video in the list that handles its own `isPlaying` state internally.

I am using a `ref` to access the video element rather than looking at DOM parent/sibling relationships.

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

type VideoProps = {
  src: string; // require an src
} & JSX.IntrinsicElements["video"]; // allow any other props of the HTML <video> element

const Video = (props: VideoProps) => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  const togglePlay = () => {
    // play or pause the video element
    if (isPlaying) {
      videoRef.current?.pause();
    } else {
      videoRef.current?.play();
    }
    // update the state
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <video
        {...props} // pass through all props to the video element
        ref={videoRef} // attach the ref
      />
      <span>
        <button onClick={togglePlay}>
          <img
            src={isPlaying ? "pause.svg" : "play.svg"}
            alt={isPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play"}
          />
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

type VideoListProps = {
  videoListItems: Array<{
    video: {
      url: string;
    };
  }>;
};

const VideoList = ({ videoListItems }: VideoListProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {videoListItems.map((item) => (
        <Video key={item.video.url} src={item.video.url} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```